# Помогите с классами android

Tags: android

У меня в приложении нужно получить два списка приложений, входящие и исходящие, эти два списка заполняют два списка RecyclerView, и потом при нажатии на элемент я перехожу на другое активити. Для заполнения этих списков я использую два адаптера:

1. Для входящих:

   ```
   public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MessageHolder> {
       private List<Message> messageList;
       private Context ctx;
       private static final String keyMessageId = "message_id";

       MessageAdapter(List<Message> messageList, Context ctx) {
           this.messageList = messageList;
           this.ctx = ctx;
       }

       @NonNull
       @Override
       public MessageHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
           View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_of_rec_m, viewGroup, false);
           return new MessageHolder(itemView);
       }

       @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MessageHolder holder, int position) {
           final Message message = messageList.get(position);

           holder.tvSubject.setText(message.getSubject());
           holder.tvFrom.setText(message.getSender_name());
           holder.tvDate.setText(message.getDate());

           holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {

                   Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,MessageShow.class);
                   intent.putExtra(keyMessageId,message.getId());
                   ctx.startActivity(intent);
               }
           });

       }

       @Override
       public int getItemCount() {
           return messageList.size();
       }


       class MessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

           final TextView tvFrom, tvSubject, tvDate;

           MessageHolder (View itemView) {
               super(itemView);
               tvFrom = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_from);
               tvSubject = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subject);
               tvDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Для исходящих:

   ```
   public class MessageAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter2.SenderHolder> {
       private List<Message> messageList;
       private Context ctx;
       private static final String keyMessageId = "message_id";

       MessageAdapter2(List<Message> messageList, Context ctx) {
           this.messageList = messageList;
           this.ctx = ctx;
       }

       @NonNull
       @Override
       public SenderHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
           View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_of_rec_m, viewGroup, false);
           return new SenderHolder(itemView);
       }

       @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final SenderHolder holder, int position) {
           final Message message = messageList.get(position);

           holder.tvSubject.setText(message.getSubject());
           holder.tvFrom.setText(message.getReceiver_name());
           holder.tvDate.setText(message.getDate());

           holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {

                   Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,MessageShow.class);
                   intent.putExtra(keyMessageId,message.getId());
                   ctx.startActivity(intent);
               }
           });

       }

       @Override
       public int getItemCount() {
           return messageList.size();
       }


       class SenderHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

           final TextView tvFrom, tvSubject, tvDate;

           SenderHolder (View itemView) {
               super(itemView);
               tvFrom = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_from);
               tvSubject = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subject);
               tvDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

но я не могу понять, вроде у меня два идентичных класса, но почему-то при нажатии на элемент списка входящих я нормально могу вытащить id сообщения и передать его на другое активити для запроса, а со списком исходящих почему-то такая система не работает, вроде как что-то передается но если смотреть логи запросов на исходящие, то сервер пишет ошибку что не может найти id сообщения. Может где-то я чего-то не дописал))

### UPDATE

Активити с которого осуществляется переход на список входящих/исходящих сообщений:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher, CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    Button submitBtn;
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    private CheckBox rem_userpass;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, tok_pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    final String ACCESS_TOKEN = "access_token";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_login);


        try {
            submitBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
            submitBtn.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.button));
            submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    sendPost();
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }


    }


    public void sendPost() {
        final EditText titleEt = findViewById(R.id.login);
        final EditText bodyEt = findViewById(R.id.password);
        final String a = titleEt.getText().toString().trim();
        final String b = bodyEt.getText().toString().trim();
        final Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://сервер/")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        //retrofit.create(APIService.class);

        mAPIService.auth(new Post(a, b)).enqueue(new Callback<GetToken>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<GetToken> call, @NonNull Response<GetToken> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Post submitted to API.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SecondScreen.class);
                    btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#1cd000"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    //TextView txt = findViewById(R.id.access_token);
                    String token = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getAccess_token();
                    //txt.setText(token);
                    startActivity(intent);


                    tok_pref = getSharedPreferences("access_token", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = tok_pref.edit();
                    editor.putString(ACCESS_TOKEN, token);
                    editor.apply();


                    saveData();

                    titleEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                            if (s.toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                                btn.setEnabled(false);
                                findViewById(R.id.btn_submit).getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                            } else {
                                btn.setEnabled(true);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                                      int after) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Unable to submit post to API.Error!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    findViewById(R.id.btn_submit).getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<GetToken> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Unable to submit post to API.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }

    private void saveData() {
        final EditText titleEt = findViewById(R.id.login);
        final EditText bodyEt = findViewById(R.id.password);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        rem_userpass = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY_REMEMBER, false))
            rem_userpass.setChecked(true);
        else
            rem_userpass.setChecked(false);

        titleEt.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USERNAME, ""));
        bodyEt.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_PASS, ""));

        titleEt.addTextChangedListener(this);
        bodyEt.addTextChangedListener(this);
        rem_userpass.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        managePrefs();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        managePrefs();
    }

    private void managePrefs() {
        final EditText titleEt = findViewById(R.id.login);
        final EditText bodyEt = findViewById(R.id.password);
        if (rem_userpass.isChecked()) {
            editor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, titleEt.getText().toString().trim());
            editor.putString(KEY_PASS, bodyEt.getText().toString().trim());
            editor.putBoolean(KEY_REMEMBER, true);
            editor.apply();
        } else {
            editor.putBoolean(KEY_REMEMBER, false);
            editor.remove(KEY_PASS);//editor.putString(KEY_PASS,"");
            editor.remove(KEY_USERNAME);//editor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, "");
            editor.apply();
        }
    }
}
```

активити на которое переходим при выборе сообщения:

```
public class MessageShow extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String keyIncomingMessageId = "incoming_message_id"; // для входящих
    private static final String keyOutboundMessageId = "outbound_message_id"; // для исходящих

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_show);
        Integer id = getIntent().getIntExtra(keyIncomingMessageId, 0);
        showMess(id);
    }

    private void showMess(Integer id) {
        final TextView tvPerson, tvTheme, tvBody;

        tvTheme = findViewById(R.id.theme);
        tvPerson = findViewById(R.id.sender);
        tvBody = findViewById(R.id.date_of);

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://сервер/")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        String ACCESS_TOKEN = "access_token";
        SharedPreferences tok_pref = getSharedPreferences(ACCESS_TOKEN, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = tok_pref.getString(ACCESS_TOKEN, "");


        APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        mAPIService.messView("Bearer " + access_token, id, 0, 1).enqueue(new Callback<ViewMessage>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ViewMessage> call, @NonNull Response<ViewMessage> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    tvPerson.setText(response.body().getName());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ViewMessage> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Буду рад советам, критике и любой другой помощи. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81388/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-goroshko----android).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я очень сильно протупил))) я только сейчас заметил, что у меня при попытке вытащить после клика на item всё сообщение, использовался только один метод, и соответственно один запрос, а у меня разные параметры запроса для входящих и исходящих))) нужно просто дописать еще один метод, так-что вопрос снимается я думаю.

Comment: рад что всё разрешилось. Вопрос наверное лучше будет удалить.

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете один и тот же ключ в `putExtra` для двух адаптеров, объявите две разные переменные типа String:

```
private static final String keyIncomingMessageId = "incoming_message_id"; // для входящих
private static final String keyOutboundMessageId = "outbound_message_id"; // для исходящих
```

Comment: я вот попробовал то что вы предложили)) и ничего не изменилось, все равно работает только список для входящих.

Comment: В вашем вопросе абсолютно идентичный код, за исключением того, что имя второго адаптера с приставкой цифры 2 и другое имя вью холдера. И если первый работает как надо, а второй не работает и вовсе, то из приведенного кода причиной могло быть только то, что ключи одинаковые используются. Так как остального кода не видно, другой ответ дать врядли получится. Ну и еще, вы выполняете одно и тоже действие в двух разных адаптерах, в чем суть?

Comment: я могу дополнить ответ активити на которою осуществляется переход, если это как-то поможет

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko дайте код другой активности